# What is the proper way of creating a 3D pie chart using Highcharts v2.3.3 ? Am I missing a critical Highcharts file?

Tags: highcharts

The option to upgrade to the latest Highcharts is NOT available.
As it is I am stuck with using a very old version of Highcharts. Version 2.3.3
If someone can help I appreciate it.

Thank you.

ps. I can post the code snippet if needed.

Comment: here's the code:

Comment: You did not attach the code and it would be better to indicate it in the question itself

Comment: Hi @user2953145, Highcharts support 3D charts since version 4.0.0. Please see the changelog: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/ You can check first release `highcharts-3d` source code: https://code.highcharts.com/4.0.0/highcharts-3d.src.js but adding it to your project can be a very difficult task.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you! I have convinced management  upgrading to the latest Highcharts version is the way to go.